# Netbeans - Customize brace matching line color

Tags: colors, customization, matching, netbeans-8, braces

Is there any option to change the color of this, very useful, line, on Netbeans 8. I tried in Formatting tab, but I didn't find the way.

Thanks a lot.

Screenshot of my current colorset

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting you need to change is "Indent Guide Lines" on the Highlighting tab of the Fonts & Colors Options.

1. **Tools->Options**
2. Select **Fonts & Colors**
3. Select **Highlighting** tab
4. Select **Indent Guide Lines** in the Category list
5. Edit the **Foreground** color as desired.
6. Click **OK**